# Stuck on reinstallation of OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan

Tags: macos, install, recovery

When I trigger the reinstallation of OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan while in Recovery Mode starting "Reinstall OS X" the InstallAssistant immediately fails:

```
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: @(#)PROGRAM:Install  PROJECT:Install-1000
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: @(#)PROGRAM:IA  PROJECT:InstallAssistant-532
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Hardware: MacBookPro12,1 @ 3.10 GHz (x 4), 8192 MB RAM
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G31)
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Env: DYLD_NO_FIX_PREBINDING=1
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Env: PWD=/
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Env: XPC_FLAGS=0x0
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Env: XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Env: SHLVL=1
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Env: __OSINSTALL_ENVIRONMENT=1
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Env: CI_DEFAULT_OPENCL_USAGE=0
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Env: OS_INSTALL=1
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Env: _=/System/Library/CoreServices/Language Chooser.app/Contents/MacOS/Language Chooser
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: Can not connect to /var/run/systemkeychaincheck.socket: No such file or directory
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: OSInstallChunkedDownload loaded...
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: OSInstallChunkedDownload loaded...
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: IAPisaDownload loaded...
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[458]: IAPisaDownload loaded...
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro Unknown[420]: 2020-03-16 00:52:25.770 InstallAssistant[458:14619] NSColorList could not parse color list file /System/Library/Colors/System.clr
Mar 16 00:52:25 MacBook-Pro Unknown[420]: 2020-03-16 00:52:25.779 InstallAssistant[458:14619] Failed to connect (keyReceivingView) outlet from (IASetupWindowController) to (PUKDiskPickerHorizontalView): missing setter or instance variable
```

When I look at the above message `Can not connect to /var/run/systemkeychaincheck.socket: No such file or directory` I guess the issue might be related to the current SIP setting, which is "enabeled".

**Question**
 Should I rerun the job with SIP switched off? Any advice how to overcome this issue is highly welcome.

**Hardware-Software-Environment**

MacBook Pro Early 2015 running OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan.
The internal HD is actually a 250 GB SSD comprising partitions EFI, Macintosh HD and Recovery HD. There is no encryption enabled on any of these partitions.

Comment: from where you got the El capitan image file ? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886 - I will try to reinstall with the proper dmg file.

Comment: @Udhy thanks for your fast reply. I started up from macOS Recovery pressing Command-R as described here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904 . I'll follow your advice and start over again first downloading an appropriate dmg file.

Comment: maybe sound stupid, but I hope your internet is quite strong. Did you try with wired connection?

Comment: @Udhy Yes, via Ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processing steps sketched below fixed the issue.

**Hardware-Software-Environment**

MacBook Pro Early 2015 running OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan.
The internal HD is actually a 250 GB SSD comprising partitions EFI, Macintosh HD and Recovery HD. There is no encryption enabled on any of these partitions.
 At the time we started the reinstallation attempt described here, the `Macintosh HD` partition is unusable as startup volume due to a previously stuck installation attempt, see question above.

**Processing Steps**

1. We boot the machine from a startup volume residing on an external HD connected via USB 3.0 Bus. Then we log in to a session in Normal Mode under OS X 10.11.6 .
2. We download a new El Capitan installation package from 
   http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-41424-20191024-218af9ec-cf50-4516-9011-228c78eda3d2/InstallMacOSX.dmg
3. We unpack the package to install the macOS installer.
4. Now we just run the installer; Internet connection off. The machine rebooted and, after approximately 30 minutes, reappeared with a login screen.
5. We could verify that OS X 10.11.6 BuildVersion 15G31 had been properly reinstalled to the `Macintosh HD` partition with no user data or previously installed third party software lost.

**Reference**
[How to upgrade to OS X El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886)

**Acknowledgement**
Thanks a lot to @Udhy for the decisive hint to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple failed attempts with an Aura ssg and being offered Yosemite 10.10 and no disk to put it on, alt command R offered me Monterey and found the Aura ssd. No idea why.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/343653)